# Ok to use external font (ttf file) for multi-language application?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have looked within Stack Overflow and online elsewhere but can't find an answer to this:

1. If I use an external font/typeface (a pretty mainstream one like Helvetica Neue Condensed) rather one of the three default Android ones (sans, serif, monospace), would/could this cause problems on how other languages (Chinese, Russian, Arabic etc) are displayed?
2. Are there any other problems that could be caused in using an external font that I should be aware of?
3. From the lack of articles and forum questions on the web, I am guessing that using external fonts is discouraged. Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This depends upon whether that font supports these languages or not. You can check this from the source you are getting that font file.
2. There will be no problems caused, apart from the limitations of the font. Like some fonts(e.g. Boycott and CharlemagneStd-Bold fonts) supports only Capital letters and changes the small ones into caps automatically.
   Also Some fonts can not render special characters or characters used in languages like Espaniol (spanish).
3. Its not discouraged at all, thing is this approach is used only in the apps where you need to get more fancy and display the things in different way.
   Like in games, promotional app for celebrities like PrinceRoyce in Android(available in Amazon Android Market only).
   In all, you can use the external fonts but you need to make sure whether it will render your texts in all the languages your app will be used.